# How to export data including large objects from Postgres and later import the exported data to Greenplum

Tags: postgresql, greenplum

I don't want to use `pg_dump` to export data into sql script, since feeding it to the greenplum cluster is too slow when I have a large amount of data to import. So it seems using greenplum's `gpfdist` is prefered. Is there any way I can do this?

Or as an alternative, can I export a particular Postgres table's data into a CSV format file containing the large orbjects of that table?

Comment: do you call `oid` a large object?..

Comment: @VaoTsun I'm not very sure about this. Say oid refers to the id of the `pg_largeobject` table should be more appropriate? I'm modifying the title.

Comment: so you want to export one your `lo` tables with data - right?.. and the generated exported "file" should be importable to some other db - right?..

Comment: @VaoTsun yes. But should not be a sql script file using `COPY`.

Comment: using `copy` you usually generate csv, and sql script you generate with `pg_dump --inserts`. I'm confused again. which one suits you?

Comment: Sorry about my poor English. I meant should not be a sql script including `COPY` and `INSERT` statement because gpfdist cannot import that format. A CSV file consists of pure data expected by `gpfdist`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pg_dump will create a file that will use "COPY" to load the data back into a database.  When loading into Greenplum, it will load through the Master server and for very large loads, it will become a bottleneck.  Yes, the preferred method is to use gpfdist but you can most certainly use COPY to load data into Greenplum.  It won't load in the 10+ TB per hour rate that gpfdist can achieve but it still can achieve 1 to 2 TB per hour.

Another alternative is to use gpfdist to execute a program to get data.  It would execute the SELECT statement against PostgreSQL to make that available to an External Table in Greenplum. I created a wrapper for this process called, "gplink".  You can check it out here: http://www.pivotalguru.com/?page_id=982

Comment: Tks, I'm going to use `COPY`, and check your `gplink` later for a study purpose. I found that from Postgres `pg_dump` generates a `lo` sql like this:`SELECT pg_catalog.lowrite(0, '\x1f8b0800000000000000a590')`, to directly import it to greenplum get a nonstandard use of escape warning if `SET standard_conforming_strings = off`, and set it to be `on` will get a syntax error. do you know how to fix this?

Comment: would you please to help me with some other questions about greenplum.[large object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40993132/how-to-dump-the-large-object-data-from-postgres-9-4-and-then-import-it-to-postg) and [unique constrains](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40987460/how-should-i-deal-with-my-unique-constraints-during-my-data-migration-from-postg)

Comment: I always use the pg_dump from the Greenplum distribution and use something like "pg_dump -Fp -n os > os.dmp".  This will backup the schema name "os" in plain text.

Answer (score 0):

[Accoridng to greenplum reference:](http://greenplum.org/gpdb-sandbox-tutorials/#lesson-4-data-loading)

> The simplest data loading method is the SQL INSERT statement...
>
> You can use the COPY command to load the data into a table when the data
> is in external text files...
>
> You can use a pair of Greenplum utilities, gpfdist and gpload, to load external data into tables...

Nevertheless if you want to use csv to import data, you can generate csv with large object "filename" joining you table against `pg_largeobject`. Eg:

```
b=# create table lo (n text,p oid);
CREATE TABLE
b=# insert into lo values('wheel',lo_import ('/tmp/wheel.PNG'));
INSERT 0 1
b=#  copy (select lo.*, pg_largeobject.pageno, pg_largeobject.data from lo join pg_largeobject on lo.p = loid) to '/tmp/lo.csv' WITH (format csv, header);
COPY 20
```

Generated `/tmp/lo.csv` will have name, oid and data bytea in csv format.

Comment: a nice and useful trick. but maybe not suitable for my situation, tks