# How should I deal with my UNIQUE constraints during my data migration from Postgres9.4 to Greenplum

Tags: postgresql, greenplum, unique-index

when I execute the following sql (which is contained by a sql file generated by  `pg_dump` of Postgres9.4) in greenplum:

```
CREATE TABLE "public"."trm_concept" (
"pid" int8 NOT NULL,
"code" varchar(100)  NOT NULL,
"codesystem_pid" int8,
"display" varchar(400) ,
"index_status" int8,
CONSTRAINT "trm_concept_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("pid"),
CONSTRAINT "idx_concept_cs_code" UNIQUE ("codesystem_pid", "code")
);
```

I got this error:

```
ERROR:  Greenplum Database does not allow having both PRIMARY KEY and UNIQUE constraints
```

why greenplum doesn't allow this? I really need this unique constraint to guarantee some rule, how can I fix it in greenplum?

Comment: 1) because greenplum is a crippled-down version of Postgres 2) you could try replace the unique constraint by a unique index.

Comment: @joop I'm sad to say unique index act the same behavior with unique constraint...

Comment: This is a much better question for http://dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: Because Greenplum is a robust analytics database engine and not an OLTP database.  The general recommendation is to not use indexes and unique constraints in Greenplum.  Also, Greenplum is NOT PostgreSQL.  It is a fork of PostgreSQL 8.2 and has come a very long way since that fork.

Comment: @JonRoberts thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- a `UNIQUE` constraint is done with a btree index
- Primary Keys imply `UNIQUE` and `NOT NULL`
- GreenPlum distributes to child/shards or whatever on whatever you claim as `UNIQUE`.

For GreenTree to implement a `UNIQUE` constraint -- as you want -- that index would have to be

- copied to every child
- updated in an ACID compliant manner

Doing that would totally remove the benefits of running GreenPlum. You may as well move back to PostgreSQL.

[From the docs about CREATE TABLE](http://gpdb.docs.pivotal.io/4380/ref_guide/sql_commands/CREATE_TABLE.html)

> When creating a table, there is an additional clause to declare the Greenplum Database distribution policy. **If a DISTRIBUTED BY or DISTRIBUTED RANDOMLY clause is not supplied, then Greenplum assigns a hash distribution policy to the table using either the PRIMARY KEY (if the table has one) or the first column of the table as the distribution key.** Columns of geometric or user-defined data types are not eligible as Greenplum distribution key columns. If a table does not have a column of an eligible data type, the rows are distributed based on a round-robin or random distribution. To ensure an even distribution of data in your Greenplum Database system, you want to choose a distribution key that is unique for each record, or if that is not possible, then choose DISTRIBUTED RANDOMLY.

Same doc says this about PRIMARY KEY,

> For a table to have a primary key, it must be hash distributed (not randomly distributed), and the primary key The column(s) that are unique must contain all the columns of the Greenplum distribution key.

Here is what the docs on [CREATE INDEX](http://gpdb.docs.pivotal.io/4320/ref_guide/sql_commands/CREATE_INDEX.html)

> In Greenplum Database, unique indexes are allowed only if the columns of the index key are the same as (or a superset of) the Greenplum distribution key. On partitioned tables, a unique index is only supported within an individual partition - not across all partitions.

Comment: Tks, Your words **Doing that would totally remove the benefits of running GreenPlum. You may as well move back to PostgreSQL.** make me understand something about greenplum.

Answer (score 0):

Many (perhaps most) analytic databases offer no support for constraints like these. Greenplum is somewhat unique in supporting enforceable `PRIMARY KEY`.

FWIW, in Redshift I run extra logic after any ETL step that changes data to ensure that my constraints are still valid.

You could try the same approach here but I would strongly suggest that you partition the table on the columns which will be checked.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to remove my primary key, and keep my unique constraint.