# How to dump the large object data from Postgres 9.4, and then import it to Postgres8.x?

Tags: postgresql, blob, greenplum

I used `pg_dump` to export the data including large objects (LO) from Postgres 9.4 like this:

```
$ pg_dump fhir -O -b > fhir.sql
```

The LO statements in my generated `fhir.sql` are like this:

```
SET standard_conforming_strings = on;
SELECT pg_catalog.lowrite(0, '\x1f8b0800000000000000a5903b6ec3300c86efa2d9b1dad5a728daa2');
```

When I executed `\i fhir.sql` in my Postgres8.2, I got this error:

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type bytea
```

When I `SET standard_conforming_strings = off`, the data was inserted, but I got a warning, and the data in my `pg_largeobject` table was:

```
14 |      0 | \0378b0800000000000000a5903b6ec3300c86efa2d9b1dad5a728daa2
```

The original `\x1f` was changed to `\037`, and I had a test, it is no longer my original zip file…

how can I fix this?

**UPDATE**:

I inserted the same original data into Greenplum(based on Postgresql8.2) with a Hibernate program, and then used `pg_dump` to export it, its format was like this:

```
SELECT pg_catalog.lowrite(0, '\\037\\213\\010\\000\\000\\000\\000\\000\\000\\000\\245\\220;n\\3030\\014')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

---

**UPDATA**

I found out an easier way to work: just use `pg_dump -b -Fc` to export data including LO into a custom file, later use `pg_restore` of the same version of `pg_dump` which you used to export data to import the custom file data into greenplum.

Scripts:

```
$ pg_dump fhir -O -a -Fc  -f fhir.dump
$ pg_restore -h mdw -d fhir -U gpadmin -a fhir.dump > errors.log 2>&1
```

---

A point fact I've missed is that `lo_export` exports binary data which is able to be imported into greenplum perfectly.

My solution(for my situation):

1. export the plain data(using `pg_dump`,exclude LO) and LO data(using `lo_export`) from Postgres9.4 separately.
2. import the plain data dump into Greenplum
3. import the LO data with `lo_import`, this will generate some new `oid`(`lo_import` with `oid` started from Postgres8.4), meanwhile update the corresponding `oid` of the referenced table with these new `oid`.

Sample scripts:

1. export plain data from Postgres9.4

   ```
    $ pg_dump fhir -O -a -n public -f fhir.dmp
   ```
2. export LO from some table containing LO data, naming the exported files with the original oids

   ```
   SELECT lo_export(res_text, '/usr/local/pgsql/export/res_lo/'||res_text) FROM hfj_resource;
   ```
3. import plain data into Greenplum

   ```
   \i fhir.dmp
   ```
4. create a function in Greenplum to import LO and update referenced oids

   ```
   CREATE FUNCTION import_lo(tab_name text, lo_path text) RETURNS void AS $$

    DECLARE

       res record;

       new_oid oid;

    BEGIN

       FOR res in EXECUTE 'select res_text from '||$1 LOOP

           new_oid := lo_import($2||'/'||res.res_text);

           RAISE NOTICE 'res_text from % to %', res.res_text, new_oid;

           EXECUTE 'update '||$1||' set res_text='||new_oid||'where res_text='||res.res_text;

       END LOOP;

       RAISE NOTICE 'import large object into % finished .....', $1;

    END;

    $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
   ```
5. import LO

   ```
   SELECT import_lo('hfj_resource', '/home/gpadmin/export/res_lo');
   ```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the dump uses the function `pg_catalog.lowrite(integer, bytea)` to create the large object, and the default syntax how `bytea` literals are represented in PostgreSQL has changed with version 9.0.

There is the parameter `bytea_output` which can be set to `escape` to output `bytea` in the old format with later PostgreSQL versions. Alas, `pg_dump` doesn't respect that parameter when creating dumps, it always uses the “new” `hex` format.

The result is that a dump containing large objects from a PostgreSQL version of 9.0 or later cannot be restored into a pre-9.0 database.

You'll have to transfer these large objects in some other way, probably by writing a migration program.

You could propose (on the pgsql-hackers mailing list) an option to `pg_dump` that allows to set `bytea_escape` for the dump, but you might meet resistance, as restoring a dump from a later PostgreSQL version to an older one is not supported.

Comment: Sad to hear that, I've also tried the `bytea_output`, setting it to `escape` doesn't work.  Thanks for your answer. Allow me to hold a glimmer of hope to wait if there were any other answers helping me.

Comment: I would try using the Greenplum version of pg_dump.  I haven't messed with large objects however so I don't know if it will work or not.

Comment: @JonRoberts Maybe Greenplum is different, but PostgreSQL's `pg_dump` refuses to connect to a server with a later version than itself.

Comment: `[gpadmin@localhost export]$ pg_dump fhir -h 192.168.2.108 -p 5432 -U postgres -O -t hfj_resource -f fhir.dmp     
Password: 
pg_dump: server version: 9.4.6; pg_dump version: 8.2.15
pg_dump: aborting because of server version mismatch`

Comment: @YinAqu Yes, that's what I expected.